# Ship a hard drive to be uploaded cloud storage

Tags: backup

I live in a place with mediocre internet access and I'm trying to backup ~5 TB of data to the cloud. I would like to ship a hard drive with the data to some service where it would be uploaded to a Google Cloud storage bucket or similar.

I've looked into Google's Transfer Appliance, as well as AWS Snowball and Backblaze Fireball, but these all cost $300+ and involve sending me a special data appliance designed for hundreds of TB.

What I really want is just to ship an ordinary hard drive with ~5 terabytes of data on it to someone, have them upload it over a fast internet connection to Google Cloud storage, and then have them ship the hard drive back to me. Can anyone suggest where I might find such a service?

Comment: Hi Alex. Great question, but unfortunately it's off-topic here on Software Recommendations Stack Exchange.  For that reason, I'm sorry, but I need to close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not find it as a commercial service per se. It's a rather niche request that anyone with a satisfactory internet connection can accomplish.

Consider to research the mom-and-pop computer stores in your desired geographical area, one with suitable internet service. You could begin by determining which areas are served by optical fiber as opposed to cable based services.

Once you have that area determined, it's reasonable to believe that a small shop would have high speed internet. A mom-and-pop business is not restricted to "by the book" service expected from the big box stores.

Your request is not extreme, nor difficult to accomplish. I don't run a shop, nor do I have optical fiber based internet, but even at a lowly 60 Mbps (no data cap), I'd consider to perform your task for a reasonable fee. A shop owner may be even more agreeable, as the transfer would happen while his shop is closed.